# Spring 3 Hibernate JPA 2.0 Maven and value '2.0' error

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, maven

Im trying to create application from scratch. In new maven project i add a lot of dependencies, create persistence.xml, application.xml and modify web.xml. Also introduce some entities and controllers. Next im trying to run it on jetty using mvn jetty:run, and then i got this exception :

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.3.1: Value '2.0' of attribute 'version' of element 'persistence' is not valid with respect to the corresponding attribute use. Attribute 'version' has a fixed value of '1.0'.
```

After googling i learnd that it might be because i have several realization of JPA in class path, and one of them probably is 1.0. But i cant understand, where it can be, because i use only latest version of hibernate entiry manager, and explicity dont add any other realization. Where there may be a bug? Can problem be because i added many spring dependencies?

```
<dependencies>
        <!-- 1111111 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- 2222222 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- 33333333 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- 4444444 -->
        <!--Core utilities used by other modules. Define this if you use Spring Utility APIs (org.springframework.core.*/org.springframework.util.*)-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--Expression Language (depends on spring-core) Define this if you use Spring Expression APIs (org.springframework.expression.*)-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--Bean Factory and JavaBeans utilities (depends on spring-core) Define this if you use Spring Bean APIs (org.springframework.beans.*)-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP) Framework (depends on spring-core, spring-beans) Define this if you use Spring AOP APIs (org.springframework.aop.*)-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--Application Context (depends on spring-core, spring-expression, spring-aop, spring-beans) This is the central artifact for Spring's Dependency Injection Container and is generally always Defined-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--Various Application Context utilities, including EhCache, JavaMail, Quartz, and Freemarker integration Define this if you need any of these integrations-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--Transaction Management Abstraction (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-aop, spring-context) Define this if you use Spring Transactions or DAO Exception Hierarchy(org.springframework.transaction.*/org.springframework.dao.*)-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--JDBC Data Access Library (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, spring-tx) Define this if you use Spring's JdbcTemplate API (org.springframework.jdbc.*)-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--Object-to-Relation-Mapping (ORM) integration with Hibernate, JPA, and iBatis.(depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, spring-tx) Define this if you need ORM (org.springframework.orm.*)-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Object-to-XML Mapping (OXM) abstraction and integration with JAXB, JiBX, Castor, XStream, and XML Beans.(depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context) Define this if you need OXM (org.springframework.oxm.*)
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>   -->
        <!--Web application development utilities applicable to both Servlet and Portlet Environments(depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context) Define this if you use Spring MVC, or wish to use Struts, JSF, or another web framework with Spring (org.springframework.web.*)-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--Spring MVC for Servlet Environments (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, spring-web) Define this if you use Spring MVC with a Servlet Container such as Apache Tomcat (org.springframework.web.servlet.*)-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--Spring MVC for Portlet Environments (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, spring-web) Define this if you use Spring MVC with a Portlet Container (org.springframework.web.portlet.*)-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--Support for testing Spring applications with tools such as JUnit and TestNGThis artifact is generally always Defined with a 'test' scope for the integration testing framework and unit testing stubs-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- 55555555 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

and my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
             xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="units" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:."/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="3"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

${org.springframework.version} = 3.0.0.RELEASE

if something else needed - i can provide

p.s. sorry for english

Comment: Based on that i would assume the spring framework version does not fit with your persistence.xml or vice versa. But i don't know from which of your persistence.xml files the error message is produced.

Comment: Perhaps you could run `mvn dependency:tree` and see if it indicates reference to an older JPA library.  You could update the question with this

Comment: Yes, probably in is true, that spring vesrion conflict with persistent.xml. After i changed version to 3.1.1.RELEASE all seems work fine. Thank you a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO your POM, its dependencies and the `persistence.xml` file looks OK. I can't see any reason why JPA 1.0 somehow have precedence over JPA 2.0, at least on your application side. Thus, you should check the other side, that is your Jetty instance you deploy the application to. Ensure that its libs (that are provided to the application classpath) don't contain JPA 1.0 (its realization, like old Hibernate version), because then JPA 1.0 has precedence. I really don't see any other reason but old JPA implementation in classpath.

Alternatively, just try to download vanilla Tomcat, unpack it and deploy your app how it is (WAR file). This will ensure you that the application is OK and this is a container's problem.